# Reference does not live long enough in nested structure

Tags: rust

I'm creating a series of data structures containing mutable references to lower level structures. I've been fairly happily working with `A`, `B`, and `C` below but I've attempted to add a new layer `D`. `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` are actually the states of a state machine for protocol decoding, but I've deleted all of that here:

```
struct A {}

fn init_A() -> A {
    A {}
}

struct B<'l> {
    ed: &'l mut A,
}

fn init_B(mut e: &mut A) -> B {
    B { ed: e }
}

struct C<'l> {
    pd: &'l mut B<'l>,
}

fn init_C<'l>(mut p: &'l mut B<'l>) -> C<'l> {
    C { pd: p }
}

struct D<'lifetime> {
    sd: &'lifetime mut C<'lifetime>,
}

fn init_D<'l>(mut p: &'l mut C<'l>) -> D<'l> {
    D { sd: p }
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = init_A();
    let mut b = init_B(&mut a);
    let mut c = init_C(&mut b);

    // COMMENT OUT THE BELOW LINE FOR SUCCESSFUL COMPILE
    let mut d = init_D(&mut c);
}
```

I get an error:

```
error[E0597]: `c` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:38:1
   |
37 |     let mut d = init_D(&mut c);
   |                             - borrow occurs here
38 | }
   | ^ `c` dropped here while still borrowed
   |
   = note: values in a scope are dropped in the opposite order they are created
```

I'm completely lacking understanding of what is happening differently for `D` compared to `C` as far as lifetimes go: I don't understand what the lifetime mismatch is.

Comment: This indeed looks surprising.  For what it's worth, your code [compiles on nightly with non-lexical lifetimes enabled](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=ac8b62c05dd2eb79b6185a3415c1c011&version=nightly).

Comment: I'm not totally sure that the NLL version working is *correct*. It seems like it has [at least one bug](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/47279).

Comment: @Shepmaster I noticed the bug as well – thanks for reporting it!  I'm not sure it's related to NLL.

Comment: @SvenMarnach right. As [noted](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/47279#issuecomment-356104081), non-NLL reports both an error *and* the warning, which is what makes me think that the fact the NLL version compiles is incorrect.

Comment: If it helps anyone, [here's a greatly reduced example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=43602054ad031b97ad6d2f69ab81476d&version=undefined) that shows the `init_` functions aren't necessary to unify the lifetimes; a struct behaves just the same on its own.

Comment: @trentcl Nice! Here's the minimal fix from my answer applied to that reduced version: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=6033a44a2cc9f6bc73934230180ba7f6&version=stable)

Answer (score 4):

I'll address the point why the code in question doesn't work.

TL;DR: Invariance over the lifetimes of types `C<'l>` and `D<'l>` and the use of a single lifetime parameter (`'l`) for them cause variables of those types to keep their borrows for as long as variable `b` exists, but variable `c` (borrowed by `d`) is dropped before `b`.

The borrow checker is essentially a constraint solver. It searches for the shortest lifetimes<sup>0</sup> which satisfy various constraints: a reference must not live longer than a value it references, lifetimes must obey constraints specified in function signatures and types, and lifetimes must obey variance rules<sup>1</sup>.

**0** — The shortest lifetime of a reference is the best because then the reference doesn't borrow a value for longer than necessary.

**1** — Rust has a concept of [variance](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/nomicon/subtyping.html) which determines whether it is possible to use a value with longer lifetime in a place which expects a value of lesser lifetime. The Rustonomicon link explains it in detail.

The code below is a simplified version of the code in question and it fails with the same error: `c` does not live long enough. The blocks are marked with the lifetimes of variables. `'a` is the lifetime of variable `a` and so on. Those lifetimes are determined by the structure of the code and they are fixed.

Lifetimes in type annotations (`B(&'ar A) -> B<'ar>` and so on) are variables. The borrow checker tries to find valid assignments of fixed lifetimes (`'a`, `'b`, `'c`, '`d`) to these variables.

The comments below the `let` statements show the lifetime constraints which I'll explain below.

```
struct A;

struct B<'l>(&'l mut A);

struct C<'l>(&'l mut B<'l>);

struct D<'l>(&'l mut C<'l>);

fn main() {
    // lifetime 'a
    let mut a = A;
    { // lifetime 'b
        // B(&'r mut A) -> B<'ar>   
        let mut b = B(&mut a); 
        // 'r >= 'ar & 'r <= 'a
        { // lifetime 'c
            // C(&'br mut B<'ar>) -> C<'abr>  
            let mut c = C(&mut b); 
            // 'br <= 'b & 'abr = 'ar & 'br >= 'abr
            { // lifetime 'd
                // D(&'cr mut C<'abr>) -> D<'cabr> 
                let d = D(&mut c); 
                // 'cr <= 'c & 'cabr = 'abr & 'cr >= 'cabr
            }
        }
    }
}
```

First assignment

```
// B(&'r mut A) -> B<'ar>   
let mut b = B(&mut a); 
// 'r <= 'a & 'r >= 'ar
```

Reference to `a` cannot outlive `a`, hence `'r <= 'a`.

`&'r mut A` is variant over 'r, so we can pass it into the type constructor of `B<'ar>` which expects `&'ar mut A` iff `'r >= 'ar`.

Second assignment

```
 // C(&'br mut B<'ar>) -> C<'abr>  
 let mut c = C(&mut b); 
 // 'br <= 'b & 'abr = 'ar & 'br >= 'abr
```

Reference cannot outlive `b` (`'br <= 'b`), `&mut B` is invariant over `B` (`'abr = 'ar`), `&'br mut B` is variant over `'br` (`'br >= 'abr`)

`d`'s assignment is analogous to `c`.

Rust doesn't seem to consider lifetimes it hasn't encountered yet as possible assignments. The possible assignments for `'ar` thus are `'a` or `'b`, the ones for `'abr` are `'a`, `'b`, or `'c` and so on.

This set of constraints boils down to `'ar = 'abr = 'cabr` and the smallest allowed assignment for `'ar` is `'b`. Therefore the types of `b`, `c`, and `d` are `B<'b>`, `C<'b>`, `D<'b>`. That is, the variable `d` holds a reference to `c` for the lifetime `'b`, but `c` is dropped at the end of the `'c` lifetime.

If we remove `d`, then `c` still keeps `b` borrowed to the end of the lifetime `'b`, but it isn't a problem because `b` doesn't outlive the lifetime `'b`.

This description is still simplified. For example, while the type of `c` is `C<'b>`, `c` doesn't borrow `b` for the entire lifetime `'b`, it borrows it for a part of `'b` starting after definition of `c`, but it is something I don't have clear understanding yet.

Answer (score 2):

The `init_*()` functions in your original code always return a type with a lifetime parameter equal to the lifetime of the reference you passed in.  Since you build a chain of references this way, all your lifetimes will end up the same, and the types of `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` will end up being `A`, `B<'a>`, `C<'a>`, `D<'a>`.  This is fine up until `c`, since the lifetime `'a` can be the scope of `b`, which satisfies all constraints.

However, once you add `d` to the mix, there is no single lifetime `'a` that would make all references valid.  The lifetime `'a` can't be the scope of `b` anymore, since `c` does not live long enough.  Neither can it be the scope of `c`, since this is too short for `b`, so the compiler errors out.

By decoupling the lifetimes, it's possible for all variables to have their own lifetime and everything works as expected.  Since the problem only starts with `D`, it's enough do introduce an additional lifetime at that point.

```
struct A;

fn init_a() -> A {
    A {}
}

struct B<'a> {
    ed: &'a mut A,
}

fn init_b(ed: &mut A) -> B {
    B { ed }
}

struct C<'b> {
    pd: &'b mut B<'b>,
}

fn init_c<'b>(pd: &'b mut B<'b>) -> C<'b> {
    C { pd }
}

struct D<'c, 'b: 'c> {
    sd: &'c mut C<'b>,
}

fn init_d<'c, 'b: 'c>(sd: &'c mut C<'b>) -> D<'c, 'b> {
    D { sd }
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = init_a();
    let mut b = init_b(&mut a);
    let mut c = init_c(&mut b);
    let d = init_d(&mut c);
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=6e0e82bac3b5b319d42a8772fb202f91&version=stable)

Comment: The code can be simplified. [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=739b95c2b3e42bd797b54bda14791154&version=stable) `C<'a, 'b>` is variant over `'a` and invariant over `'b`. This allows to write `sd: &'a mut C<'b, 'b>`.

Comment: Another way to make the original code compile: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=59218f6657f4b7b9db53b2d404926167&version=stable) `let (mut b, mut c, d);` makes lifetimes of `b`, `c`, and `d` exactly the same.

Comment: @red75prime you should go ahead and make that an answer (along with the explanation of why it works)

Comment: I understand that I can jiggle the code around to make it compile: for example I can also,in my real use case, stop using references at all and transfer ownership of `a` to `b`, and then of `b` to `c` and so on - so that everything goes out of scope all at once with `d`.

What I was really wondering is why this compiles with `A`, `B`, and `C`, but not when I add in `D`.

Comment: @Shepmaster, I've a draft of the answer, but I need to make it clearer for everyone, me included. There's nontrivial interplay of lifetimes.

Comment: @red75prime indeed. Perhaps [some discussion between nikomatsakis and pnkfelix](https://gitter.im/rust-impl-period/WG-compiler-nll?at=5a54ddf219147ac3231b60dd) would help?

Comment: @BenClifford The function calls are making all reference lifetimes equal in your code, so you end up with the types `A`, `B<'a>`, `C<'a>`, `D<'a>`.  This is fine up until `c`, since the lifetime `'a` can be the scope of `b`.  However, once you add `d` to the mix, there is no single lifetime `'a` that would make all references valid, so you have to use more than one.  I've gone a bit overboard by simply giving everything a separate lifetime – it's possible to make to with less, but I'm too lazy to work out the details.

Comment: @red75prime I've updated the answer with simpler code as you suggested and also added more detail to the explanation I gave.