# Does a generic lifetime materialize as the reference's lifetime or the referenced value's lifetime?

Tags: rust, lifetime

Consider the following program:

```
fn main() {
    let c;                                      |<-'a
    let mut a = "Hello, world!".to_string();    |
    {                                           |
        let b = &mut a;           |<-'b         |
        c = foo(b);               |             |
    }                                           |
    println!("{}", c)                           |
}

fn foo<'z>(a: &'z mut str) -> &'z str {
    a
}
```

`b`'s lifetime is `'b`, but `c`'s lifetime is `'a`, which is longer than `'b`. `foo`'s lifetime constraint says `foo`'s return value (`c` in this case) should have the same lifetime with its argument (`b` in this case). How is `foo`'s lifetime constraint satisfied?

However, this program compiles, so I guess `foo`'s lifetime parameter `'z` materializes as `b`'s referenced value (`a`)'s lifetime so that `foo`'s lifetime constraint is satisfied?

Comment: It seems you just answered your own question. What else are you expecting?

Comment: Just want to confirm if my logic and guess is correct, and are there any exceptions to my guess?

Comment: `b` has the type `&'a mut str`. The lifetime of the reference would be the scope that owns the value. In this case, you didn't move `a` into `'b`, so your reference is still `&'a`. However, if you pass `&b` into `foo` (even if the type matches), you will get error because `b` lives inside `'b`.

Comment: The lifetime of a borrow expression isn't necessarily the same as the lifetime of any variable. The compiler doesn't have to *choose* an output lifetime from the input lifetimes, it can create a "new" lifetime that satisfies the requirements any place there is a borrow expression. (also note `foo(b)` does an implicit reborrow, so the type of `c` and the type of `b` don't need to have the same lifetime parameter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A value has a lifetime of its own, but a reference also tracks the lifetime of the thing it references. Unfortunately, there's a lack of official terminology to use here. The term that I (and some others) have started using is *concrete lifetime*. There are three variables in main and thus there are three concrete lifetimes:

```
fn main() {
    let c;                     //       'c
    let mut a = String::new(); // 'a     ¦
    {                          //  |     ¦
        let b = &mut a;        //  | 'b  ¦
        c = foo(b);            //  |  |  |
    }                          //  |     |
    println!("{}", c)          //  |     |
}
```

`a` is a `String`, `b` is a `&mut String`, and `c` is a `&str`. All three variables are values, but `b` and `c` are *also* references. In this case, `b` refers to the value in `a` and is `&'a mut String`. Since `c` is derived from `b`, it has the same "inner lifetime": `&'a str`.

Notably, the lifetime of `b` itself **never** comes into play. It's exceedingly rare for it to, as you need to have mutable borrows and an "extra" borrow:

```
fn main() {
    let c;
    let mut a = String::new();
    {
        let mut b = &mut a;
        c = foo(&mut b);    // Mutably borrowing `b` here
    }
    println!("{}", c)
}
```

```
error[E0597]: `b` does not live long enough
 --> src/main.rs:6:17
  |
6 |         c = foo(&mut b);
  |                 ^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
7 |     }
  |     - `b` dropped here while still borrowed
8 |     println!("{}", c)
  |                    - borrow later used here
```

In this case, the value passed to `foo` is of type `&'b mut &'a mut String`, which is coerced down to `&'b mut str`. The value `b` does not live long enough, and you get the error.

> I don't think this model can account for more complicated borrowing relationships. If `a` is used again after the `println!`, for example, the mutable borrow can't be for the entire lifetime of `a`

The mutable borrow of `a` is held by `c`, but the *duration of the borrow* doesn't need to correspond to the lifetime of `c`. Due to [non-lexical lifetimes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50251487/155423) (better called "non-lexical borrows" in this context), the borrow of `a` held by `c` can terminate after the `println!` but before the end of scope.

Enhancing the the diagram from above to show the lifetime of the *value* combined with the lifetime of the *referred-to value* in parenthesis:

```
fn main() {
    let c;                     //           'c
    let mut a = String::new(); // 'a         ¦
    {                          //  |         ¦
        let b = &mut a;        //  | 'b('a)  ¦
        c = foo(b);            //  |  |('a)  |('a)
    }                          //  |         |('a)
    println!("{}", c);         //  |         |('a)
                               //  |         |
    println!("{}", a);         //  |         |
}
```

See also:

- [Why does linking lifetimes matter only with mutable references?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32165917/155423)
- [How can this instance seemingly outlive its own parameter lifetime?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42637911/155423)
- [Mutable borrow in a getter not living long enough](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51502717/155423)
- [Reference does not live long enough in nested structure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48158063/155423)
- [Cannot borrow as mutable more than once at a time in one code - but can in another very similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31067031/155423)
- [What is the difference between '&self' and '&'a self'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45833618/155423)

Comment: I don't think this model can account for more complicated borrowing relationships. If `a` is used again after the `println!`, for example, the mutable borrow can't be for the entire lifetime of `a`.

Comment: Better. We're dealing with a lack of precision in terminology, as you mention. It still doesn't match my own mental model, but I might be overfitting.